Is it possible to create a mobile VPN application for Android using Ionic + Capacitor + Vue 3?
Please advise, is it possible to create a mobile VPN application for Android using Ionic + Capacitor + Vue 3? Or would it be better not to delve into this and instead focus more on native mobile development languages?
There is very little information on this topic on the internet, not a single decent article can be found.

I would say it depends on what you mean by "mobile VPN application". If control over the device's hardware (ie network) definitely not.

you have to write a native plugin for this. and when you are writing core login in native then why writing UI on ionic ??
